# Using wget to get URL's beginning with certain string

Tags: unix, web-scraping, wget

So I'm trying to use wget to download all my tweets. Since all the links to my tweets begin with http://www.twitter.com/UserName/ ... I am trying to use wget for this.

I assumed wget -m -r would work but it doesn't. I've done some digging and have not found a way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will not work, because the link to every tweet looks like UserName/status/id and the id is something you don't know. You should use https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170320# instead

Comment: Oh ok, so I'm guessing there no way to use wget to download URL's beginning with a certain string? Also thanks for the link

Comment: `-r` is not needed, `-m` already does that. From what I can tell, I doubt it will work because of lots of javascript and AJAX in the twitter UI. This might be interessting, too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/411540/how-to-get-wget-to-download-exact-same-web-page-html-as-browser